# Low bluetooth signal strenth on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, iwlwifi

grep -i bt_coex_active /etc/modprobe.d/*

```
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=Y
```

After doing this also
I could not able to find the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try disabling the Wifi and then check if the bluetooth strength gets better ? I was facing the same issue and it got solved by enabling and disbaling the Wifi.
Will be waiting for your response.